# USB HD on Boot: The disk drive for UUID is not ready yet or is not present

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount

I'm a Windows user by necessity (work), so I'm not 100% sure of what I'm doing here.  I put Ubuntu on my father-in-law's computer because he was breaking Windows every month.  As hard as I'm sure he tries, he can only break Ubuntu about once a year.

He has an external hard drive for his music. If I plug it in after booting and logging in, it works fine.  If I either edit fstab manually or using the Disks utility so that the drive mounts at startup, I get the error message.

Here's what's in fstab:

```
UUID=c2068ce0-cc7a-4e4d-a07b-561e6a52da9d /media/external ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

The drive is formatted ext4.  The UUID is correct, as far as I can see.  /media/external does exist, and as far as I can tell, it has the correct permissions (owner is root, but other users can read and write).

The one other potential curveball is that the computer is a Dell workstation with a slight BIOS issue.  It shows a battery voltage error at startup. You have to hit F1 to continue.  The battery is fine; it's apparently an issue with these computers.  The BIOS settings are still saved.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [thread](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) in terms of how to mount a drive. 
On the side notes don't worry about that " battery voltage error at startup". I have an old Dell studio(2009) who's adapter and battery has been replaced(bought some non original stuff from amazon and ebay)...i used to get this error message. Press F1 and good to go.If you want to get rid of that forever...just enter into BIOS and there is a setting not to show errors of this type(some adapter kind of wordings)